# Apache Tomcat startup error

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, eclipse-wtp, documentum

I'm receiving this error when starting tomcat:

```
16:27:21,027 ERROR [main] com.documentum.web.common.Trace - An error occurred during application intialization : org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet
    at com.documentum.services.preset.impl.PackageDefinitionLoader.loadPackageDefinitionFromFile(PackageDefinitionLoader.java:117)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a jar which contains an import of the org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet class.

Most probably this is the org.eclipse.emf.common plugin jar which is missing.

Comment: Adding ecore-2.1.0.jar which contains that class and an another one common-2.1.0 causes a linkage error

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet` could not be found during runtime. You must add all **Documentum** dependencies to the classpath.

Comment: any idea where I can find this class? I already added all the documentum jars to the build path

Comment: The class seems to be ecore-2.1.0.jar from the eclipse modeling framework.. it doesn't look like a dctm class